Need help finding martial arts movie from early 80's Sunday Matinee
I am looking for a martial arts movie I saw in the early 80's on Sunday matinee (TV).  A young man wanted to train at a local martial arts school.  He attempts to sneak into the school and is caught.  As punishment he is forced to train even though they think he isn't capable.
I remember that there was a walk way to the "lunch area" and in that walk way was a pool of water.  In the water was a "log" of bamboo tied together.  The students had to jump onto the log to get over the pool.  This young man was not able to get across, but he kept trying until one day he got better than the others.  So the next time the ropes were rigged to break when he touched the "log".  He still made it across because he was so light on his feet.
Another aspect of training was carrying something heavy (don't remember what, maybe buckets of water) with knives strapped to the upper arms to prevent the student from lowering their arms.
This is all I can remember.  I have tried searching google and imdb with no luck.
Any thoughts?

A possiblity might be the rather famous The 36th Chamber of Shaolin:

The anti-Ching patriots, under the guidance of Ho Kuang-han, have secretly set up their base in Canton, disguised as school masters. During a brutal Manchu attack, Lui manages to escape and devotes himself to learning the martial arts in order to seek revenge. In a short period of time he masters the deadly use of his fists, feet and palms, along with such weapons as swords, sticks, and lances. With his learning complete, he takes on the Manchus.

But I'm absolutely unsure about this and haven't seen it for a long time. The only argument I can bring for this movie is that your description of having to somehow get over a pool of water to lunch and carrying buckets as part of the training immediately evoked memories to this movie in me. And he also isn't an official trainee in the school, being only tolerated under the assumption that he won't get far anyway, if I remember correctly.

You were correct.  I should have done some more searching because I saw a description of this movie and didn't think it was the same.  Once I looked up images of this movie on Google images I found the scenes that I remember.  Now if I can just find a place to watch it.
